# Dynamically Deleting selected rows in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and need some help in deleting the rows dynamically.     I have the below HTML + Javascript code. I am inserting the rows using clonenode which is working as expected. Now I want to select (using click event) a specific row from the table and delete it. I don't want to add any buttons in each row to identify the rows. Can someone help me on this.

```
<html>
<head>   
<style>
  #quottable 
  {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    margin-left: 2cm;   
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #dde; 
    font-size: 11px;
 }
 #quottable1
 {
        font-size: 11px;
 }
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var xy=0;

    var EmpInfo = [
    {
    EmpID:'42001',
    EmpName:'Peter',
    Salary:'1000'
    },
    {
    EmpID:'42002',
    EmpName:'Henri',
    Salary:'2500'
    },
    {
    EmpID:'42003',
    EmpName:'John',
    Salary:'4500'
    },
    {
    EmpID:'42003',
    EmpName:'Paul',
    Salary:'4500'
    },      
    ];  

function GetEmpTab() 
{  
    if (xy===0)
    {
    document.getElementById('EmpListTab').rows[0].innerHTML=EmpInfo[0].EmpName;
    for (var i = 1; i < EmpInfo.length; i++)
    {             
        var x=document.getElementById('EmpListTab');                        
        var new_row = x.rows[0].cloneNode(true);                        
        x.appendChild( new_row );   
        var name = EmpInfo[i].EmpName;
        new_row.innerHTML=name;         
    }
        xy=1;
    }
}              
</script>       
</head>

<body> 
<div id="quottable" style="width:154px; height:450px;">
<Table id="EmpListTab" width="154" border="1">  
<tr height="50px">   
<td style="text-align:left" id="Q1B" height="50"></td>
</tr>
</Table> 
</div>  
<button onClick="GetEmpTab();">Insert a new row!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "selected". If you simply want to delete a row if a click occurs anywhere in the row, then a listener on the row like `onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)"` will do the job. But you might want a target area and two step process to confirm the delete.

Comment: @RobG - Sorry. I think my question was not clear. I want to select a specific row from a set of rows. Based on the selection, I am going to display some more details(like in another window). So I need to identify which row, I have selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can just identify the selected row using a css class.

```
<tr height="50px" onclick="this.className='selected_row';">   
    <td style="text-align:left" id="Q1B" height="50"></td>
</tr>
```

Elsewhere

```
<stlye>
    .selected_row{background-color: yellow;}
</style>
```

To exclusively select one row at a time,

```
<tr height="50px" onclick="select_row(this);">   
    <td style="text-align:left" id="Q1B" height="50"></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
function select_row(target){
    var prevs = document.getElementsByClassName("selected_row");
    for(var i=0; i<prevs.length; i++){
        prevs[i].className = "";
    }
    target.className='selected_row';
}
</script>
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: This is just for example and this only works if you're only using one class name for your table rows. This is NOT recommended for any useful implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback..This is a good idea. I am trying to implement next step. When a select a row, I want to deselect the other rows. (i.e) As per your idea, when I click the rows one by one, background color for all my rows becoming yellow. Is there a way to reset the background color for remaining rows, when select a specific row?

Comment: This would be very easy if you use Jquery or any JS framework. In pure JS, you need to remove that class name from all the other rows which have it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you go beyond simple functionality, you need to string together your own library of functions and then build custom functionality on top. E.g. the following uses a very small library of functions to help out.

It attaches a listener to the table that, when it gets a click from a row, selects or deselects that row. Any other row that might be selected is deselected. It then uses a button to find the selected row (if there is one) and deletes it.

```js
// Library functions
var util = {
  // Remove leading and trailing whitespace
  // Reduce internal whitespace to a single space
  trim: function(s) {
    return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s+/,' ');
  }
};

var dom = {
  // Return true if el has class className, otherwise false
  hasClass: function(el, className) {
    return util.trim(el.className).split(/\s+/).indexOf(className) != -1;
  },
  
  // Add class className to el if it doesn't have it already
  addClass: function(el, className) {
    if (!dom.hasClass(el, className)) {
      el.className += (el.className == ''? '':' ') + className;
    }
  },
  
  // Remove class className from el if it has it
  removeClass: function(el, className) {
    if (dom.hasClass(el, className)) {
      var classes = util.trim(el.className).split(/\s+/);
      classes.splice(classes.indexOf(className), 1);
      el.className = classes.join(' ');
    }
  },
  
  // Add class Classname to el if it doesn't have it, 
  // otherwise remove it
  toggleClass: function(el, className) {
    if (dom.hasClass(el, className)) { 
      dom.removeClass(el, className);
    } else {
      dom.addClass(el, className);
    }
  },
  
  upTo: function (el, tag) {
    tag = tag.toLowerCase();
    do {
      el = el.parentNode;
    } while (el && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != tag)
    return el && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag? el : null;  
  },
  
  select: function(selector, root) {
    root = root && root.querySelector? root : document;
    return root.querySelector(selector);
  },
  
  selectAll: function(selector, root) {
    root = root && root.querySelectorAll? root : document;
    return root.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
};

// Custom functions

// Toggle selected class on row clicked on
// Remove selected from all other rows 
function selectRow (evt) {
  var tgt = evt.target || evt.sourcElement;
  var row = dom.upTo(tgt, 'tr');
  if (!row) return;
  var seletedRows = document.querySelectorAll('tr.selected');
  for (var i=0, iLen=seletedRows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (seletedRows[i] != row) {
      dom.removeClass(seletedRows[i], 'selected')
    }
  }
  dom.toggleClass(row, 'selected');
}

// Remove tr elements with class selected
function deleteSelectedRows() {
  [].forEach.call(dom.selectAll('tr.selected'),function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
  });
}

window.onload = function (){
  dom.select('#table0').addEventListener('click', selectRow, false);
}
```

```css
.selected  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table0">
  <tr><td>row0<td>row0
  <tr><td>row1<td>row1
  <tr><td>row2<td>row2
  <tr><td>row3<td>row3
</table>
<button onclick="deleteSelectedRows()">Delete selected rows</button>
```

The maintenance for such libraries is quite minimal and made easier if you also apply some discipline to the related documents to avoid "edge cases". Most of it is just ECMAScript ed 3 that works anywhere, and the ES5 bit is easily shimmed. There's nothing that relies on ECMAScript 2015.

There are some great HTML5 functions to do the class stuff, but it's not sufficiently ubiquitous yet to rely on. When it is, those functions can be reduced to one line and maybe removed altogether.